# WCF and Inheritance

Tags: wcf, inheritance

I'm working on a project where I have an abstract class of Appointment. There are Workouts, Meals and Measurements that all derived from Appointment. My architecture looks like this so far:

Dao - with data access layer being entity framework 4 right now
POCO classes using the T4 templates
WCF
Silverlight Client, ASP.net MVP, mobile clients

Would I put business rules in the POCO class? or map my Entities to a business object with rules and then map those to DTOs and pass those through WCF?? and when I pass the DTOs do I pass over type Appointment? Or write a service method for each sub class like Workout or Meal?

I haven't found any good material using table per type inheritance and WCF.

thanks in advance!

-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it mainly depends on complexity you require. You are using POCO classes it is good starting point. You now have to choose how complex application are you going to build, how much business logic do you want to add and what do you want to expose to your clients?

The POCO entity can be just DTO or you can turn POCO entity into business object by adding business methods and rules directly into that entity - you will transform the entity into Active record pattern or to Domain object. I don't see any reason to map your POCOs to another set of business objects.

Exposing POCO entity in WCF service is the simplest way. You can use operations which will works directly with Appointment class. Additionally you have to give your service information about all classes derived from Appointment - check [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) and [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx). Using entity often means that service calls transport more than is needed - this can be problem for mobile clients with slow internet connection. There is one special point you have to be aware of when exposing entity which is aggregation root (contains references to another entitities and collection of entities) - if you don't have full control over client applications and you allow clients sending full modified object graph you have to validate not only each entity but also that client changed only what he was allowed to. Example: Suppose that client want to modify Order entity. You send him Order with all OrderItem entities and each item will have reference to its Product entity = full object graph. What happens if instead of modifing Order and OrderItems client changes any of Products (for example price)? If you don't check this in your business logic exposed by WCF and pass the modified object graph into EF context, it will modify the price in your database.

If you decide to use your entities like business objects you usually don't expose those entities, instead you will create large set of DTOs. Each operation will work with precisely defined DTO for request and response. That DTO will carry only information which are really needed - this will reduce data payload for service calls and avoid passing modified prices of product, because you will simply define your DTO to not transfer price or even whole product from the client. This solution is much more time consuming to implement and it adds additional layer of complexity.

Because I have mentioned object graphs I must clarify that there is another hidden level of complexity when using them: change tracking. EF context needs to know what have changed in object graph (at least which OrderItem was modified, which was added or deleted, etc.) for correct persistence. Tracking and multi tier solution is a chalenge. The simplest solution does not track changes and instead uses additional query to EF. This query returns actual persisted state of object graph and modified object graph is merged with it (special care is needed for concurrency checks). Other solutions uses some tracking support in entity - check [Tracking changes in POCO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456848.aspx) and [Self-tracking entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx). But this is only for entities. If you want to track changes in DTO you have to implement your own change tracking. You can also read articles from MSDN magazine about multi tier applications and EF: 
[Anti-Patterns To Avoid In N-Tier Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx);
[Building N-Tier Apps with EF4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx)

Comment: WOW! What a great thoughtful answer! Thank you very much :)